# CanvasJS having a seperately scaled Y-Axis

Tags: canvasjs

I'm still a bit new to CanvasJS, but one thing I've been struggling with is trying to have separately scaled Y-Axis's for each of my lines in a spline chart.

I'm hoping someone can point out what I'm missing. So far I've spent the day working on this and haven't been able to get very far. I'm hoping it's something small.

```
window.onload = function () {

        var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("timeline", {
    theme: "light2",
    animationEnabled: true,
    title: {
        text: "Bowling stats over time"
    },
    toolTip: {
        shared: true
    },
    legend: {
        cursor: "pointer",
        itemclick: toggleDataSeries
    },
    data: [{
        type: "spline",
        visible: true,
        showInLegend: true,
        yValueFormatString: "##",
        name: "Pinfall",
        yAxisID: 'y2',
        dataPoints: [
            { label: "2023-12-07", y: 151 },
            { label: "2023-12-11", y: 103 },
            { label: "2023-12-14", y: 156 },
            { label: "2023-12-15", y: 132 }
        ]
    }, {
        type: "spline",
        visible: true,
        showInLegend: true,
        yValueFormatString: "##",
        name: "Strikes",
        yAxisID: 'y',
        dataPoints: [
            { label: "2023-12-07", y: 2 },
            { label: "2023-12-11", y: 1 },
            { label: "2023-12-14", y: 4 },
            { label: "2023-12-15", y: 2 }
        ]
    }, {
        type: "spline",
        visible: true,
        showInLegend: true,
        yValueFormatString: "##",
        name: "Spares",
        yAxisID: 'y',
        dataPoints: [
            { label: "2023-12-07", y: 4 },
            { label: "2023-12-11", y: 1 },
            { label: "2023-12-14", y: 2 },
            { label: "2023-12-15", y: 3 }
        ]
    }, {
        type: "spline",
        visible: true,
        showInLegend: true,
        yValueFormatString: "##.00",
        name: "First Throw Avg",
        yAxisID: 'y',
        dataPoints: [
            { label: "2023-12-07", y: 8.7 },
            { label: "2023-12-11", y: 6.4 },
            { label: "2023-12-14", y: 7.9 },
            { label: "2023-12-15", y: 7.7 }
        ]
    }],
    responsive: true,
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        id: 'y',
        stacked: false,
        position: 'left',
        type: 'linear',
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
        }
      }, {
        id: 'y2',
        stacked: false,
        position: 'right',
        type: 'linear',
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
chart.render();

    function toggleDataSeries(e) {
        if (typeof(e.dataSeries.visible) === "undefined" || e.dataSeries.visible ){
            e.dataSeries.visible = false;
        } else {
            e.dataSeries.visible = true;
        }
        chart.render();
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0mp3gkyz/

In my sample code I'm just trying to use two separate yAxis controls for the sake of testing, but ideally, I'd like to have a seperate scaled access per line.

Answer (score 0):

Your code basically uses `CanvasJS` but not `Chart.js`.

```
new CanvasJS.Chart("timeline", {
   ...
}
```

Part of the chart configuration however (in particular `options`) is borrowed from `Chart.js`. Note that these are different products with their own syntax each.

> To solve your problem, please take a look at the `CanvasJS` how-to page [Creating Chart with
> Multiple Y Axis](https://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/how-to/multiple-y-axis/).